# Laravel Collection get one of values by key

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel and I'm trying to get one of the values in one collection by one ID retrieved from another collection.

My function returns 2 Collections:

```
public function index()
{
    $category = BlogCategory::all(['id', 'name']);        
    $post = BlogPost::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(14)->get();
    return view('blog.index', ['posts' => $post],  ['categories' => $category]);
}
```

In a foreach loop I'm getting values from collections:

```
    @foreach($posts as $post)
     @if($loop->iteration > 2)
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 d-flex justify-content-center other-post">
          <a href="#">
             <img src="#" alt="">
             <p class="post-category">{{ $categories->get($post->category_id) }}</p>
             <h5 class="post-title">{{ $post->title }}</h5>                        
          </a>
         </div>
      @endif
     @endforeach
```

I'm partially getting the result as you can see in the image below, but I want to get only the name.

[image: Example Result]

Here is the code that I'm trying to figure out
`{{ $categories->get($post->category_id) }}`

If there is a better or correct way to do it, let me know.

Blog Posts migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('blog_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->longText('content');
        $table->mediumText('slug');
        $table->bigInteger('author_id')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('blog_authors');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('blog_categories');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put in place the relationships between `BlogPost` and `BlogCategory` models, seen that you already have a `category_id` field in `BlogPost` model, i.e.:

in `BlogPost` Model:

```php
public function category(){
   return $this->belongsTo(\App\BlogCategory::class);
}
```

in `BlogCategory` Model:

```php
public function posts(){
   return $this->hasMany(\App\BlogPost::class);
}
```

Next you can [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) `categories` with the `$posts` in your controller with only two queries:

```php
public function index()
{        
    $posts = BlogPost::with('category')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(14)->get();
    return view('blog.index', compact('posts'));
}
```

Then in your view you can access each `$post->category` object directly because eager loaded in the controller:

```php
@foreach($posts as $post)
 @if($loop->iteration > 2)
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 d-flex justify-content-center other-post">
      <a href="#">
         <img src="#" alt="">
         <p class="post-category">{{ $post->category->name }}</p>
         <h5 class="post-title">{{ $post->title }}</h5>                        
      </a>
     </div>
  @endif
 @endforeach
```

Comment: `"Undefined variable: categories"`

Comment: I don't have any $categories variable in my code you should have posted in the wrong answer, please try my code.

Comment: Sure. It was needed to restart the server. It worked as needed.

Comment: use eager loading instead of lazy loading it will make (n+2) SQL opartion

Comment: I don't think so @Joseph, the controller/view code I posted executes only two queries on the BlogPost and BlogCategory model, try it by yourself.

Comment: make `dd()` to your posts collection and check if it has a category object in it,
you will not find it.

Comment: the controller is eager loading: `BlogPost::with('category')` that are two queries, please read here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 1):

It could be optimized, first, you need to make relation one to many from categories to posts

**first**: make sure that you have in posts migrations `category_id` column

**Second**: Open Category Model and write this method this will allow you to fetch posts that belong to the category

```
public function posts(){
   return $this->hasMany(\App\Post::class);
}
```

**Third**: open shop model and write this method this will allow you to fetch category that belongs to the post

```
public function catgeory(){
   return $this->belongsTo(\App\Category::class);
}
```

**Finally**: you will edit your view like this one

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 d-flex justify-content-center other-post">
      <a href="#">
         <img src="#" alt="">
         <p class="post-category">{{ $post->category->title }}</p>
         <h5 class="post-title">{{ $post->title }}</h5>                        
      </a>
     </div>
 @endforeach
```

and of course, you wouldn't call categories in your controller anymore

```
public function index()
{        
  $post = BlogPost::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(14)
          ->with('category')->get();
  return view('blog.index', ['posts' => $post]);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to eager load categories with BlogPost, your controller/view code will send 15 queries instead of only two.

Comment: Nice one I forget it I will fix it now thank for noticing me

Comment: `Call to undefined relationship [categories] on model [App\BlogPost]`

Comment: sorry i write categories instead of category in controller it will be like this
`$post = BlogPost::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(14)->with('category')->get();`

Comment: Yes, it worked. But I've tried another correct answer before yours.

Comment: @AlanGodoidaSilveira thanks :) but I would mention something the answer before me make (n+2) SQL query because every time you say `$post->category->title`
it make new query but in my case, it will compose it in the first query in the controller by using `with()` method this technique called eager loading

Comment: Sure. Accepted answer is using eager loading too.

Answer (score 0):

this line `$categories->get($post->category_id)` return for you an array of `category`, so the solution for you here is just like bellow:

```
{{ $categories->get($post->category_id)['name'] }}
```

Comment: It gives a error: `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object `

Comment: `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`

Comment: @AlanGodoidaSilveira actually as the returned value from get method is a simple array, check now

Comment: what do you mean by order, please? how many names per line do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it better use a relation to drive this situation. You can load in the controller the data in this way.

In the Model Post:

```
function categories(){
return $this->belongsToMany('App\BlogCategory')->select(array('id', 'name');
}
```

Maybe is hasOne -> the relationship if you don't have a table pivot...

In the Controller:

```
    public function index()
{     
    $data['posts'] = BlogPost::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(14)->with('categories')->get();
    return view('blog.index', $data);
}
```

In the View:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
     @if($loop->iteration > 2)
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 d-flex justify-content-center other-post">
          <a href="#">
             <img src="#" alt="">
             <p class="post-category">{{ $post->categories->name }}</p>
             <h5 class="post-title">{{ $post->title }}</h5>                        
          </a>
         </div>
      @endif
     @endforeach
```

Comment: With belongsToMany: `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'eaglehorn.blog_category_blog_post' doesn't exist (SQL: select `id`, `name`, `blog_category_blog_post`

Comment: With hasOne: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'blog_categories.blog_post_id'`

Comment: You need add column that related both tables. Maybe if field related is category_id:

return $this->hasOne('App\BlogCategory','category_id')->select(array('id', 'name');

Comment: Relationship load information related between tables. Check the information at:
if the relation is one to one:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one
if you have some categories for each post: one to many
https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many